# Invalid operands to binary * (have ‘ab {aka struct a}’ and ‘ab * {aka struct a *}’)

Tags: c, linux, pointers, structure

I wrote a program to swap two structures in an array and my coding is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct a {
    char *name;
    int id;
    char *department;
    int num;
};
typedef struct a ab;

void swap(ab *, ab *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ab array[2] = {{"Saud", 137, "Electronics", 500}, {"Ebad", 111, "Telecom", 570}};
    printf("First student data:\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%d", array[0].name, array[0].id,
           array[0].department, array[0].num);

    printf("\nSecond Student Data\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%d\n", array[1].name, array[1].id,
           array[1].department, array[1].num);

    swap(&array[0], &array[1]);
    // printf("")
    return 0;
}

void swap(ab *p, ab *q){
    ab tmp;
    tmp = *p
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

On compiling it it gives an error,

> newproject.c: In function ‘swap’: 
>   newproject.c:26:3: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘ab {aka 
>   struct a}’ and ‘ab * {aka struct a *}’) 
>   *p=*q;

What is the mistake?

Comment: Sometimes errors are not on the line that gets reported, but on one of the previous lines. Take a look at the previous line and see if that looks okay. Like for example maybe not missing a semicolon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't compiler report missing semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135392/why-doesnt-compiler-report-missing-semicolon)

Answer (score 9):

There's a missing semicolon at the end of line 26 (the previous line).

```
tmp=*p
```

Due to this, the compiler considers the next line to be part of the same statement, meaning that the entire statement is interpreted as:

```
tmp=*p * p = *q;
```

The second `*` is seen as a multiply of two operands - `*p` and `p` - which is where the error message comes from:

> invalid operands **to binary *** (have ‘ab {aka 
>    struct a}’ and ‘ab * {aka struct a *}’)

(Because `*p` is of type `ab`, and `p` is of type `ab *`).